# Rebinning numpy array by non-integer factor

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, resampling, numerical-integration

I have a grid of model spectra, which have a constant, very high spectral resolution, and I need to down-sample them to a lower resolution, while preserving the total number of counts.

In essence, if the first 5 bins have (nominal center-of-bin) wavelengths `[7.8, 7.81, 7.82, 7.83, 7.84]`, and the values `[1.01, 1.02, 1.015, 1.014, 1.02]`, and my desired bins are some (non-integer) factor (say, 2.5) times as wide, I want my new spectrum to have nominal wavelengths `[7.81, 7.83]` and values `[1.01+1.02+0.5*1.015, 0.5*1.015+1.014+1.02]` (in general, though, the bins are not lined up as well, so you may get fractions of bins on either side).

I'll call my grid `spec_ssp`, and it has a `shape` of `(93, 16, 39848)`. Wavelength varies along axis 2, and the first two axes are other parameters. I also have the nominal (central) wavelengths for each wavelength bin (technically, they're the log of the wavelength, but that shouldn't matter), called `logL_ssp`, and the desired new spacing of the logL grid, `dlogL_new`. I can figure out the nominal logL spacing of my templates `dlogL_ssp` by calculating `np.median(logL_ssp[1:] - logL_ssp[:-1])`, and it's about 20% the desired logL spacing. We'll call that fraction `f`.

I originally tried to use `scipy.ndimage.zoom`, using the aforementioned factor `f`, but discovered that it gives me an array that's downsampled by a factor of **exactly 4**. I need an exact resampling, so this won't work.

Next, I tried linearly interpolating along axis 2 using `np.interp1d`, after setting up new bin limits, with the aim of integrating the spectra in my grid using `np.integrate.quad` between successive bin limits, effectively getting an estimate of the total light in each of my new bins, more or less rigorously. However, `quad` doesn't play nicely with `interp1d`'s interpolators (`quad` doesn't like non-float inputs). And, since I have ~1500 model spectra, the whole thing takes ages to run while iterating over all three axes (yes, I'm only making a new interpolator once per model spectrum).

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Trying to answer the same (or similar) question; I'm also dissatisfied with ndimage.zoom because it looses information when downsampling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047874/scipy-ndimage-interpolation-zoom-uses-nearest-neighbor-like-algorithm-for-scalin