# scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom uses nearest-neighbor-like algorithm for scaling-down

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

While testing scipy's zoom function, I found that the results of scailng-down an array are similar to the nearest-neighbour algorithm, rather than averaging. This increases noise drastically, and is generally suboptimal for many application.

Is there an alternative that does not use nearest-neighbor-like algorithm and will properly average the array when downsizing? While coarsegraining works for integer scaling factors, I would need non-integer scaling factors as well.

Test case: create a random 100*M x 100*M array, for M = 2..20 
Downscale the array by the factor of M three ways:

1) by taking the mean in MxM blocks 
2) by using scipy's zoom with a scaling factor 1/M 
3) by taking a first point within a

Resulting arrays have the same mean, the same shape, but scipy's array has the variance as high as the nearest-neighbor. Taking a different order for scipy.zoom does not really help.

```
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean1, mean2, var1, var2, var3  = [],[],[],[],[]
values = range(1,20)  # down-scaling factors

for M in values:
    N = 100  # size of an array 
    a = np.random.random((N*M,N*M))  # large array    

    b = np.reshape(a, (N, M, N, M))  
    b = np.mean(np.mean(b, axis=3), axis=1)
    assert b.shape == (N,N)  #coarsegrained array

    c = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(a, 1./M, order=3, prefilter = True) 
    assert c.shape == b.shape

    d = a[::M, ::M]  # picking one random point within MxM block
    assert b.shape == d.shape

    mean1.append(b.mean())
    mean2.append(c.mean())
    var1.append(b.var())
    var2.append(c.var())
    var3.append(d.var())

plt.plot(values, mean1, label = "Mean coarsegraining")
plt.plot(values, mean2, label = "mean scipy.zoom")
plt.plot(values, var1, label = "Variance coarsegraining")
plt.plot(values, var2, label = "Variance zoom")
plt.plot(values, var3, label = "Variance Neareset neighbor")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Performance of scipy.ndimage.zoom on a real noisy image is also very poor

[image]

The original image is here http://wiz.mit.edu/lena_noisy.png

The code that produced it:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom

im = Image.open("/home/magus/Downloads/lena_noisy.png")
im = np.array(im)

plt.subplot(131)
plt.title("Original")
plt.imshow(im, cmap="Greys_r")

plt.subplot(132)
im2 = zoom(im, 1 / 8.)
plt.title("Scipy zoom 8x")
plt.imshow(im2, cmap="Greys_r", interpolation="none")

im.shape = (64, 8, 64, 8)
im3 = np.mean(im, axis=3)
im3 = np.mean(im3, axis=1)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(im3, cmap="Greys_r", interpolation="none")
plt.title("averaging over 8x8 blocks")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried the same comparison using an image rather than random noise? `zoom` uses spline filtering, which will be pretty useless if there's no spatial structure within the image.

Comment: Also, it's not obvious to me why low variance in the downsampled image *should* be considered a measure of quality. Isn't local averaging basically guaranteed to give you less variance than spline-based methods, whilst preserving less of the information content in the original image?

Comment: All digital images have random noise (e.g. from high ISO); a correct down-sampling algorithm would average over small blocks of an image to reduce the high-ISO noise.  In this case I fed only noise to the algorithm, and I was hoping that it would reduce the noise (i.e. reduce the variance of a random noise). I can do a control with an actual image too.

Comment: Low variance in the output image is not the same thing as noise reduction. Trivially, I could make a "downsampling algorithm" that just filled every pixel in the output with some constant value, and this would achieve zero variance - a perfect score according to your metric. Obviously this would be useless, since it preserves none of the actual spatial structure within the original image.

Comment: Could you show the code that generated those images?

Comment: Added it in a new edit.

Comment: You could use `scipy.misc.lena` to generate the test image so that others can reproduce it. FYI I get slightly nicer results using `zoom` with that version of the Lena image, although I agree that the local mean does a better job for down sampling.

Comment: @MaximImakaev Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did. On https://bitbucket.org/mirnylab/mirnylib  in mirnylib.numutils there is a function zoomArray. I basically wrote a function that up-sizes an array to larger size that can be block-averaged into a desired size. https://bitbucket.org/mirnylab/mirnylib/src/37343398ff804315e328f74251c8d47d7c99f501/mirnylib/numutils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Apparently `zoom` is only intended to zoom in, not out. If they allowed the filter basis to get wider in proportion to the amount of size reduction it would work great, unfortunately there's a lot of software out there that has the same problem. I think you'll find that it is actually doing interpolation, but without widening the filter it retains frequencies above the Nyquist limit and produces the artifacts you see. Using a higher order interpolation is not the same thing and could actually make the problem worse.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody posted a working answer, so I will post a solution I currently use. Not the most elegant, but works.

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.ndimage
def zoomArray(inArray, finalShape, sameSum=False,
              zoomFunction=scipy.ndimage.zoom, **zoomKwargs):
    """

    Normally, one can use scipy.ndimage.zoom to do array/image rescaling.
    However, scipy.ndimage.zoom does not coarsegrain images well. It basically
    takes nearest neighbor, rather than averaging all the pixels, when
    coarsegraining arrays. This increases noise. Photoshop doesn't do that, and
    performs some smart interpolation-averaging instead.

    If you were to coarsegrain an array by an integer factor, e.g. 100x100 ->
    25x25, you just need to do block-averaging, that's easy, and it reduces
    noise. But what if you want to coarsegrain 100x100 -> 30x30?

    Then my friend you are in trouble. But this function will help you. This
    function will blow up your 100x100 array to a 120x120 array using
    scipy.ndimage zoom Then it will coarsegrain a 120x120 array by
    block-averaging in 4x4 chunks.

    It will do it independently for each dimension, so if you want a 100x100
    array to become a 60x120 array, it will blow up the first and the second
    dimension to 120, and then block-average only the first dimension.

    Parameters
    ----------

    inArray: n-dimensional numpy array (1D also works)
    finalShape: resulting shape of an array
    sameSum: bool, preserve a sum of the array, rather than values.
             by default, values are preserved
    zoomFunction: by default, scipy.ndimage.zoom. You can plug your own.
    zoomKwargs:  a dict of options to pass to zoomFunction.
    """
    inArray = np.asarray(inArray, dtype=np.double)
    inShape = inArray.shape
    assert len(inShape) == len(finalShape)
    mults = []  # multipliers for the final coarsegraining
    for i in range(len(inShape)):
        if finalShape[i] < inShape[i]:
            mults.append(int(np.ceil(inShape[i] / finalShape[i])))
        else:
            mults.append(1)
    # shape to which to blow up
    tempShape = tuple([i * j for i, j in zip(finalShape, mults)])

    # stupid zoom doesn't accept the final shape. Carefully crafting the
    # multipliers to make sure that it will work.
    zoomMultipliers = np.array(tempShape) / np.array(inShape) + 0.0000001
    assert zoomMultipliers.min() >= 1

    # applying scipy.ndimage.zoom
    rescaled = zoomFunction(inArray, zoomMultipliers, **zoomKwargs)

    for ind, mult in enumerate(mults):
        if mult != 1:
            sh = list(rescaled.shape)
            assert sh[ind] % mult == 0
            newshape = sh[:ind] + [sh[ind] // mult, mult] + sh[ind + 1:]
            rescaled.shape = newshape
            rescaled = np.mean(rescaled, axis=ind + 1)
    assert rescaled.shape == finalShape

    if sameSum:
        extraSize = np.prod(finalShape) / np.prod(inShape)
        rescaled /= extraSize
    return rescaled

myar = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
rescaled = zoomArray(myar, finalShape=(3, 5))
print(myar)
print(rescaled)
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW i found that order=1 at least preserves the mean a lot better than the default or order=3 (as expected really)